# Prove that $\{(x_1,x_2):\cos(x_1 + x_2) \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le \frac{\pi^2}{4}\}$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

> Prove that $$ \left\{x=(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \cos(x_1 + x_2) \ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le \frac{\pi^2}{4}\right\}$$ is convex.

How should I do this? Hessian is made out of $-\sin(x_1 + x_2)$ so I can't determine if it's a positive definite matrix...And besides, there are two functions making the set, so does that mean I have to make two Hessians and both have to be positive definite for the set to be convex?

Comment: what does $cos(x_1,x_2)$ mean?

Comment: That was supposed to be a plus ;)

Comment: I was wondering since when cos takes two arguments.

Comment: @khernik What is the question?

Comment: How to prove that this set is convex?

Comment: Is the second set a disc or what ?

Comment: You may be mixing up convexity of a function with convexity of a set. Do you know the difference?

Comment: @khernik Oh it's actually a nice question. I think if you edit it a bit (a set is not "made of two functions") you'll receive good hints.

Comment: @khernik : what does "made of two functions" mean?  Does $\mathbf{x}$ have to satisfy both equations?

Comment: Edited. Help :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Since $|x_i|\le\pi/2$, the condition $\cos(x_1+x_2)$ is equivalent to $-\pi/4\le x_1+x_2\le\pi/4$, that is $x_2\ge-x_1-\pi/4$ and $x_2\le-x_1+\pi/4$. Now you may use the fact that the intersection of convex sets is convex.